# How do you show that the projection operator for a diffeomorphism is $\textsf P^\prime = \textsf {fP}\textsf{f}^{-1}?$

Tags: differential-geometry, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

The pseudoscalar $I(x)$ defines a projection operator that projects an arbitrary multivector onto the component that is intrinsic to the manifold,

\begin{equation}
\textsf P(A(x)) =
\begin{cases}
A_r(x)\cdot I(x) I^{-1}(x) = A_r \cdot II^{-1} & r \leq n \\
0 & r > n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The action of any linear function on a pseudoscalar satisfies

$$
\textsf f(I) = (\det \textsf f) I
$$

If $\textsf f$ is a diffeomorphism mapping multivector fields to some primed manifold, we also have (equation 2.272, Doran and Lasenby)

$$
\textsf f(I) = (\det \textsf f)I^\prime
$$

Thus $I=I^\prime$, isn't that a contradiction? Or are these identical pseudoscalars, merely represented in different coordinates?

Supposedly, we also have eq 6.287

$$
\textsf P^\prime = \textsf {fP} \textsf f^{-1}
$$

which suggests that in fact $\textsf P^\prime \neq \textsf P$, meaning $A\cdot I^\prime {I^{\prime}}^{-1} \neq A\cdot I I^{-1}$. But if $I=I^\prime$, then wouldn't we get $\textsf P = \textsf P^\prime$?

Comment: I think you're getting confused by the word pseudoscalar. In ambient $n$-dimensional space, $I(x)$ is *not* an $n$-vector unless your manifold is a region with non-zero $n$-volume (in which case your reasoning is correct). So when our manifold has dimension $k < n$, there's no reason that $f(I) = (\det f)I$ because $I$ is a $k$-vector and not an $n$-vector.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\diff\mathsf
\newcommand\adj[1]{\overline{\diff{#1}}}
$

Suppose the ambient space in which we define our $k$-dimensional vector manifold $M$ is $\R^n$. It is true that if $J$ is any $n$-vector, then for any linear $f : \R^n \to \R^n$ we have $f(J) = (\det f)J$.

But **the pseudoscalar field $I(x)$ of $M$ is a $k$-vector field**, so this does not apply unless $k = n$. Even then, we do not a priori have any reason to think of $M$ and $M' = f(M)$ as living in the same space, so comparing $I$ and $I'$ is meaningless. Think of the case that $k=2$; does it make sense to say that some tangent plane of $M$ and some other of $M'$ are parallel? It could given additional context, but it need not.

I think the way Doran and Lasenby introduce Eq. 6.272 is bad and extremely misleading. The equation
$$
  \diff f(I) = (\det\diff f)I'
$$
is a **definition** of $\det(\diff f)$; $I$ and $I'$ have to be specified beforehand for this to make sense.

---

As for $P$ and $P'$, the easiest way to get this is to use tangential derivatives $\partial$ and $\partial'$:
$$
  a\cdot\partial = P(a)\cdot\partial,\quad
  a\cdot\partial' = P'(a)\cdot\partial'.
$$
This follows simply from the fact that $a\cdot\partial = 0$ when $a$ is orthogonal to $M$ (and similarly for $M'$).
Using the fact that $\partial = \adj f(\partial')$ (which is just the chain rule), it follows that
$$
  P'(a) = a\cdot\partial'x' = a\cdot\adj f^{-1}(\partial) f(x) = P(\diff f^{-1}(a))\cdot\partial f(x) = \diff f(P(\diff f^{-1}(a))).
$$

Answer (score -1):

I think what is happening is that indeed $I=I^\prime$, but $I^\prime$ may superficially "look" different because it is constructed from primed vectors.

As for $\textsf P^\prime$, I believe it is defined by $\textsf P^\prime (A^\prime) = A^\prime \cdot I^\prime {I^\prime}^{-1}$, thus we can write

\begin{align*}
\textsf P^\prime(A^\prime)
&= A^\prime\cdot I^\prime {I^\prime}^{-1} \\
&= A^\prime\cdot I {I}^{-1} \\
&= \textsf f \textsf f^{-1}(A^\prime\cdot I I^{-1}) \\
&= \textsf f \textsf f^{-1} \left( (A^\prime \rfloor I) \rfloor I^{-1} \right) \quad \textrm{(Dorst syntax)} \\
&= \textsf f \left( \overline {\textsf f^{-1}}^{-1} (A^\prime \rfloor I) \rfloor \textsf f^{-1}(I^{-1}) \right)
\end{align*}

Now, using the general formula for an inverse $\textsf f^{-1}(B) = \frac{\overline{\textsf f} (B\rfloor I^{-1}) \rfloor I }{\det \textsf f}$, we can compute the factor

$$
\textsf f^{-1}(I^{-1}) = \frac{ \overline{\textsf{f}}(I^{-1}\rfloor I^{-1})\rfloor I }{\det \textsf f} 
= \frac{I }{\det \textsf f}
$$

These functions have the property $\overline{\textsf g^{-1}}=\overline{\textsf g}^{-1}$, so  $(\overline{\textsf{f}^{-1}})^{-1} = \overline{\textsf{f}}$.

Then

\begin{align*}
\textsf P^\prime(A^\prime)
&= \frac{1}{\det \textsf f} \textsf f \left( \overline{\textsf{f}} (A^\prime \rfloor I )\rfloor I^{-1} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\det \textsf f}  \textsf f \left( \left(\overline{\overline{\textsf{f}}}^{-1} (A^\prime) \rfloor \overline{\textsf{f}}(I )\right) \rfloor I^{-1} \right) \\
&= \textsf f \left( \left(\textsf{f}^{-1} (A^\prime) \rfloor I \right) \rfloor I^{-1} \right) \\
&= \textsf{fP}\textsf{f}^{-1} (A^\prime)
\end{align*}

so $\textsf P^\prime = \textsf {fPf}^{-1}$.

Comment: Your first sentence is nonsense. Putting that aside, in your derivation of $P'$ how are you getting the second equality?

Comment: $A^\prime \cdot I^\prime {I^\prime}^{-1} = \textsf f( A\cdot I I^{-1} ) = \textsf f ( \textsf P(A) ) 
 = \textsf f ( \textsf P (\textsf f^{-1}(A^\prime) )$

Comment: $I$ and $I^\prime$ seem to be identical, they are merely expressed in different coordinates. The coefficients and basis vectors are different, but they add up to an identical quantity

Comment: I don't see why the first equality should be true; all we can say initially is $$A'\cdot I'I^{-1} = \mathsf f(A)\cdot\mathsf f(I) \mathsf f(I)^{-1}$$ (with the determinants cancelling out). As for the relationship between $I$ and $I'$, that is a much better way to phrase what you were trying to say, but that statement is false. Imagine $f$ as deforming the initial manifold $M$ to $M'$. Saying $I = I'$ is the same as saying that *every possible way of deforming $M$ keeps tangent spaces parallel at every point*, i.e. the tangent space at $f(x)$ is always parallel to that at $x$.

Comment: The pseudoscalar had grade n, and by Doran/Lasenby's GA definition, $I^\prime$ has unit magnitude. Like scalars, it has no orientation (aside from $\pm 1)$. The pseudoscalar of convential differential geometry might be quite different from the GA pseudoscalar, I know nothing about the former one.

Comment: I have read Doran and Lasenby. I promise you that you are misunderstanding what they mean by "pseudoscalar" in this situation. The pseudoscalar **of a vector manifold** $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ of dimension $k$ is a $k$-vector field $I(x)$ which represents the tangent space $T_xM$, which is considered a subspace of the ambient space the vector manifold is embedded in. This is not the same as the pseudoscalar **of the algebra/ambient space**, which is an $n$-vector. If $I(x)$ were an $n$-vector field, then $x \mapsto I(x)$ would be a constant function and $P(A) = A\cdot II^{-1} = A$.

Comment: You go wrong with your new derivation of $P'(A')$ in the first step where you say $A'\cdot I'I'^{-1} = A'\cdot II^{-1}$. The operation $A'\cdot I$ does not make sense since $A'$ and $I$ live in different spaces. Put another way, you are claiming that $P'(A') = P(A')$.

That aside, exploiting the properties of the contraction is how I would go about this from the $A'\cdot I'I'^{-1}$ definition, so I think you are heading in a good direction.